# Magento: Change default language

Tags: magento

I've searched for this for hours again, so here I am!

How do you change the default (English) language to any other language in Magento? Basically, I want all my customer from store B to arrive at the French version of the site first by default, not the English.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set those variables in .htaccess

`SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "here put store_code from BO for french version"`

`SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"` <- this leave as it is

Comment: Thanks for your help Lrrr. My "Store" is "ProCycleAylmer", "Name" is "Français", "Code" is "procycle_fr". I'm using the "index.php" version instead of .htaccess since I'm in a subfolder and running multiple websites from the same Magento installation.  When I replace "here put store_code" for "procycle_fr", the server crash and give me a 404 error. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you help me on this one, I think it's the most solid/reliable way to do it.

Comment: Ha! Finally! Since I was using magento 1.3.2.4, the code is not exactly the same. I have a folder that load magento and redirect to the good url, so I'm using the "index.php" version. The code is : Mage::run('procycle_fr');   , where "procycle_fr" is you "Store code". REF: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup.  Thanks all for you help, I hope this will help other people as well :)

Comment: Needed this too. Works in CE 1.7 also

Answer (score 9):

In the admin menu **System > Configuration**, the first tab shown should be **General** and it includes a **Locale** section. That is where you set a store's language. You can choose which store it applies to with the scope selection in the top left of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Precision: For some reason, I didn't see the option in "Current configuration scope" in "System > Configuration". Basically, I have 3 stores, 1 unilingual (the default magento installation), then we added 2 more bilingual stores (French, English). So in the drop-down, I have "ProCycleAylmer" which is my "main" config for this store, then below it I have "English" and "Français". So if I click on "ProCycleAylmer" and change the "locale" from "English - US" to "French - Canada", the website now loads in French first.

Comment: AFTERNOTE: for some weird reason, it seems to work 50%... Basically, when you enter the website, the selected language is "English", my menu is French, some text is french, categories are english, Blocks are english. What is wrong?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure why the languages are mixed. Perhaps the french bits are being cached from before you changed the config, clearing the cache is an easy fix for that.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Magento Admin

> System > Configuration
>
> Current Configuration Section from  left side bar
>
> Go to general block and then go to Local Options and select your default language and click on save config and clear your cache from admin then got to frontend and refresh the page you will see the default language is set to your desired language.

Answer (score 2):

Login to backend then go to System > Manager Stores > Click "Main Website Store" and chose default Store you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache mod_rewrite for this purpose, check following rule :

```
## Redirect according to user's language
## you can put .htaccess file
RewriteEngine on

# French Users 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [L,R=301] 

# Default Page 
RewriteRule ^$ /en/main-page [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but this is not what I'm looking for. Most French canadians have English operating system/browser for 3 reasons: #1 we don't care if it's English or French since most people are bilingual, #2 French+Microsoft=bugs when we install some french application with english application it sometimes cause bugs which are annoying, #3 when our OS/browser is in French, then google return results from France, which is very annoying. Nobody wants a dentist in Paris when you live in Montréal. So therefore just checking the computer language won't do.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your admin System => Manage Stores => Click on the "default store view" in your case English Store (Change the sort order to (1) as this will become additional store view.)

And after click on the French store view Keep the sort order as zero (0) as this will be your default language.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to magento admin => System -> Configuration. Then from the top left in "Current Configuration Scope:" select your stores and then click on Configuration of left side in GENERAL section click on General then click on "Locale Options" then select French from the dropdown in Locale section.

Answer (score 1):

1. download language files and place them into the right folders (app > local)
2. Login to admin panel and go to System > Manage stores
3. Create a new store view
4. Login to admin panel and go to System > Configuration > General
   and select each store view from “Current Configuration Scope” drop down menu at the upper left corner of the window.
   Set the corresponding locale for each store view
5. Clear the cache (System – Cache Management)

In order to set the default language for magento, you must go to System > Manage Stores, click on the “Store Name” and set the default language from there

Beware of the content of your language pack. It must have been tested that it works properly.

Reference: [Magento language pack installation](http://www.pctechblog.com/magento/magento-language-pack-installation)

Comment: excellent answer but the link got too old. You may find the localization packages at [magento translations](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations)

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything that's written here except for changing .htaccess...

Nothing worked but I found another way:

1. System->Manage Stores
2. click on Main Website Store
3. change Default Store View to French
4. refresh the cache if it's not disabled yet

May be it's version dependent - mine is 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about his code but you could give a try for below code:

Add a language pack In Magento store view:

Creating a store view for a language is not too hard in magento follow the steps given below and you are done with it.

Step 1: Download the language pack you need and then unpack it to your Magento install folder.
It copies two folders: one goes to app\design\frontend\default\default\locale
and the other one to app\locale.

Step 2: Go to System > Configuration in your admin. On the left top corner in Current Configuration Scope dropdown box, you can see Default Config, and Main Store in English store view.

Step 3: Now let’s go and add the French store view. Under the dropdown box, there’s Manage Stores link or you can directly go to System > Manage Stores. Click the Create Store View link on top right, and type these in store view information form:

Store: Main Store

Name: French

Code: french

Status: Enabled

Sort order: 0

Step 4: Save, go back to System > Configuration. In Current Configuration Scope dropdown box, you now see there’s French store view. Click that link.
On Locale options tab on the left, uncheck the ‘use website’ checkbox then change the locale to French (France). Save.

Now you can have your website in French.

Answer (score 0):

If no store is specifically set in `MAGE_RUN_CODE`, Magento displays the store with the lowest `sort_order`. Log in to your Magento Admin and go to `System -> Manage Stores`. Here, select each store and change the `Sort Order` field until the store you want to use as your default has the lowest sort order

Answer (score 0):

```
    System -> Configuration    

    1) if you have multiple store then:

    Left upper corner (below menu-links) you will see "Current Configuration Scope:" select store from there.
    after that continue to step 2

    2) if single store then:

    left side "General" -> "Default Country"
    if "Default Country" not selectable then please uncheck "Use Website" right site to country box

Thanks,
Chirag Nandaniya
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link and installed this extension in your magento store http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-french-france-language-pack.html

and setup/create store view for french

Go to admin->system->configuration and do following steps

and from admin side just setup Country option to France by clicking on General Tab located in left side and also set default Currency by clicking on  Currency Setup located in left side

but be careful to select Store view from first before applied above things from Current Configuration Scope: located on left side panel.

let me know if you have still facing any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is:

Go to **System > Manage Stores**. Click your main store name (for example **Main Website Store**) and in **Default Store View** field select French (I guess you have already created French as a Store View Name).