# Remove default language in Magento

Tags: magento

I am in the following bind:

A client wanted 3 languages - English, Russian and Latvian. Naturally, I created 3 store views and changed the language for each. Once I had translated everything via the inline-translate tool, and the client added the products with descriptions in all of the languages,the client had a change of heart, and now wants English to be removed.

Now this is a problem, since it is the default Store view, and can;t be deleted as such. i have thought of just changing the titles and locales of the languages, but that would still leave the product descriptions wrong.

Is there a way to do this, either via DB, or some other way?

**TL; DR: How to remove the default store view in Magento?**

Comment: I don't know much about Magento, but might this be helpful? [Magento: Change default language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5367033)

Comment: @Pekka웃 sadly - no. I've already done that, as a quick fix, but i want to make this permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change "Default Storeview" for your default "Store". Go to "System/Manage Stores", choose your store and change "Default storeview" to Russian or Latvian. Then you could be able to delete English storeview.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. I thought that there should be an easy way to do this, but I somehow discarded this possibility. Thanks a lot! Worked!